# Keywords status tracking for different scrapers maintaining retrieval speed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, search, web-scraping, web-crawler

To make a better understanding here is are the tables/models of my scraping app in Ruby on Rails with MySQL:

- Scraper (A scraper searches a given site for all keywords)
- Keyword (Contains term to search & a status(:search, :searching, :searched))

The system is multithreaded, so I had to add a column for status so that multiple threads wouldn't be searching the same term simultaneously.

Initially I had one scraper & everything was working fine. Now new requirement is to run multiple scrapers simultaneously.

This means a single status field will not work for all scraped. The very first option comes to mind is to make a many to many relationship of scrapers & keywords to keep track the searched keywords for each scraper.

Now I have around 1 million keywords & there are around 60-70 sites to be searched. This means a huge table which will slower the keyword retrieval process.

I am looking for a better solution which will not affect speed. I can't move to NoSQL due to some restriction from client.

Comment: Have you considered integrating Redis?

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah Its a NoSQL solution which will take some time & estimated budget won't allow it. Anyhow somehow I found a working solution.